# Apache virtual host does not work properly

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I have read a lot of information all over the Internet regarding this subject, and can not figure out what I'am doing wrong. I'm trying to host two websites under different names locally under Windows 7 with Apaches Virtual Hosting functionality. This is what I have done already:

In the httpd.conf file I uncommented the following line, so that the virtual host configuration file will be included in the main configuration sequence.

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

This is how I edited my httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
#
# Virtual Hosts
#
# If you want to maintain multiple domains/hostnames on your
# machine you can setup VirtualHost containers for them. Most configurations
# use only name-based virtual hosts so the server doesn't need to worry about
# IP addresses. This is indicated by the asterisks in the directives below.
#
# Please see the documentation at 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/>
# for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
#
# You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
# configuration.

#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
NameVirtualHost *:80

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
#<VirtualHost *:80>
#    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.localhost
#    DocumentRoot "C:/apache/docs/dummy-host.localhost"
#    ServerName dummy-host.localhost
#    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.localhost
#    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.localhost-error.log"
#    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.localhost-access.log" common
#</VirtualHost>
#
#<VirtualHost *:80>
#    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.localhost
#    DocumentRoot "C:/apache/docs/dummy-host2.localhost"
#    ServerName dummy-host2.localhost
#    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.localhost-error.log"
#    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.localhost-access.log" common
#</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>

 ServerName arterieur
 DocumentRoot "J:/webcontent/www20"

 <Directory "J:/webcontent/www20">
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
 </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

As you can see I commented the Virtual Host examples out and added my own one (I did one for this example). Also am I sure that `J:\webcontent\www20` exists.

At last I edited the Windows host file located in: `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`, now it looks this:

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost

    127.0.0.1   arterieur
```

Then I restarted Apache with the Apache Service Monitor, and it gave me the following fatal error: `The requested operation has failed!`, I tried to look at the `apache/logs/error.log` file but I did not log anything, I guess it only logs the errors after startup.

Does anyone knows what I'am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test your config with this commandline:

`httpd -t`

This will tell any error in config files.

Maybe you receive this error: `ServerName takes one argument, the Host name and port of the server.`

Try to configure it like this:

`ServerName arterieur.localhost`

and in the `hosts` file add this:

`127.0.0.1   arterieur.localhost`

This way is configured the way ServerName has to be configured.

If this does not work, use `ServerAlias` instead of `ServerName`.

And if this does not work, check that your Apache service is not disabled: Open `services.msc` and check the Apache service, make sure it's not disabled. It should be set to Manual or Automatic start-up, depending on your environment.

**EDIT:** Now talking with questioner we reached an answer:

The exact problem was that running `httpd` by service, the process don't had permissions to write to the `J:` drive, but when running it in commandline everything worked fine.

As @Jori said, `services.exe` runs under `SYSTEM` user, so seems that running `httpd` by service inherits `services.exe` rights, so he changed `J:` drive permissions for user `SYSTEM` and then worked fine.

Comment: I will try this tomorrow and report back then. I do not have an apache executable however, did you mean htppd?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the error, going to edit it.

Comment: I tested your solution and at first when running `httpd -t` it outputed: `httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName`. Now it is just `Syntax Ok`. But I still get the same error message, what is your other solution?

Comment: Use `ServerAlias` instead of `ServerName`. I'm going to add it to the answer.

Comment: Nope :( . Still the same problem, also syntax is still ok. Thanks for your help anyway, if you have other solutions or need extra information from me, please ask or post (: .

Comment: Hmmm... try to start apache from console instead of service by running `httpd`, maybe it outputs the key. Use `-w` if the window closes and you can't read the error.

Comment: I tried `httpd -k start` but it outputs nothing at all.

Comment: Well this is strange, I just tried reaching my website from `arterieur.localhost` and guess what, it works, although apache service monitor says that it is not currently running?! But only when I enter `httpd` in the console and let the process stay active there.

Comment: Yes, the service monitor wont notice `httpd` if you don't start the service. If the configurator test gave an error the first time, maybe the error was the one I told you in the reply. Please, accept the answer by clicking the `V` at his left if you liked it :P

Comment: We are going to do one thing, we are going to check what commands are the Apache Service Monitor setting to `httpd` when it tries to start it. Wait a second and I tell you.

Comment: When I check the services it says: `httpd.exe -k runservice`. Also starting up using the service monitor still fails.

Comment: Try to run that from console, but like this: `httpd -k runservice -e debug` to see what happens.

Comment: No output, process exits immediately.

Comment: Wait, I think I got it. Going to edit answer.

Comment: Wait... I think we are on the right track. It is set to automatic but it is not started. When I try to start it, it outputs: Can not start Apache2.2 on Local computer. Look at your system log files for further information. If this is not a Microsoft service contact the manufacturer. The services specific error code was: 1. (this is a translation of the message, the OS is not set to english)

Comment: Check that the path of `httpd.exe` in the service matches with your corrent location.

Comment: I'm finding those messages on the internet, maybe we are lucky :P

Comment: The file path is correct.

Comment: Check Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Event Viewer for more descriptive errors, that's your System Log, where your error tells to look. I'm going to eat something, when I return I check your messages.

Comment: Haha, we are not supposed to chat like this here, but who cares: have a nice dinner, will report back (; .

Comment: Well I checked the application log files and it showed something interesting. It appears that the directory path j:/webcontent/www20 is rejected with an syntax error (however syntax is fine and directory exists). It says for example `DocumentRoot must be a directory`. Perhaps it has something to do with apache being on a different partition than the website is?

Comment: Are you sure that the path is exactly `j:/webcontent/www20`? Maybe there's a typo somewhere. Also, Apache needs permissions for those directories.

Comment: Ok, seems that Apache only has permissions to read files from the installed partition, you have to add to the user Apache permission to read from `J:`

Comment: Ok, check that by right clicking the `J` unit and then clicking the Security tab, there should appear all users with their permissions. I suggest you to add the write permission too, maybe they are needed for your PHP scripts to save files (Don't know for sure).

Comment: Done that. I gave the group Everyone every permission. Still not working. Is the apache user included in this group? Also I'm 100% sure that `j:/webcontent/www20` exists, as I copied the path into the explorer and got the corresponding directory.

Comment: Don't think that adding permissions to Everyone will work. This has to be the problem because if you launch httpd from console, you are launching it with your account rights (Admin) and works, while launching it from servie manager launches it with Apache user, and does not work. Wait I search a bit more.

Comment: Found it!! A guy has exatly the same problem as you: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=33679 Read the last post.

Comment: Wait, this is for Linux, going to search Windows.

Comment: Again I reached the same conclusion, a permissions problem: http://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?t=3311 Just try to find the Apache user and give permissions to himself instead of Everyone group. Also, try to give permissions to all groups/users and check if that works, if works then sure is a permission problem.

Comment: I think it works now! I noticed there was an account named `SYSTEM` that had rights on almost every file on the `C:` drive but not on the `J:` drive, when I gave it rights for the `J:` drive the service monitor restarted, and also the service is now running again. Give me a minute to test this for sure and I'll accept your answer. Shame I have only 1 point and can not give you any credit. You deserve at least a 100 points for all your effort, thanks! By the way, What is that `SYSTEM` account anyway?

Comment: lol :P Is an account over Admin accounts, is the "main" account. If you check TaskManager and press the button "show all users processes" at the bottom, you will see that some critical processes are running under SYSTEM. Seems that there is not Apache user and Apache launches it under SYSTEM user. Glad it worked! Btw, you can vote up and give me 10 more points hehehe :P

Comment: Yes of course I know that, I have spend a lot of time on stackoverflow, but you can only vote up when you have reached 15 rep :-(.

Comment: Ow how awkward lol. I don't knowed that. Well, thanx for accepting :-)

Comment: I will up vote once I reached 15 rep lol. Yes it seems that `services.exe` runs under the `SYSTEM` user. I think that the Apache service process inherits its permissions from this user.

Comment: Owww perfect, that makes so much more sense now! Now I know :P I'm going to edit answer just in case someone else has the same problem.

Comment: Yes, I think that would be a good idea. It is not something you would except at first. Again, thanks for all the help.